# Finding generators of equivariant cohomology

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold with symplectic form $\omega$, carrying a Hamiltonian action of a compact connected Lie group $G$ with moment map $\mu:M\to \mathfrak{g}^\ast$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. Let $H^\ast_G(M)$ be the equivariant cohomology of $M$. In the Cartan model, the elements of $H^\ast_G(M)$ are represented by equivariantly closed equivariant differential forms, which are polynomial maps $\mathfrak{g}\to \Omega^\ast(M)$, where $\Omega^\ast(M)$ is the space of differential forms on $M$. Now, the simplest non-trivial equivariantly closed equivariant differential form one can think of is
$$
\rho(X):= \omega + \mu(X),\qquad X\in \mathfrak{g},
$$
which is closed by the very definition of the moment map $\mu$ and the equivariant differential (depending on sign conventions, one might have to choose $-$ instead of $+$ in the formula for $\rho$). From $\rho$ one can construct more equivariantly closed forms by taking $P(\rho)$ for some polynomial $P$.

My main questions are:

**For which Hamiltonian $G$-spaces $(M,\omega,G,\mu)$ can all interesting (in particular, non-exact) equivariantly closed forms be obtained as $P(\rho)$ for some polynomial $P$?**

**What if we restrict ourselves to the circle group $G=S^1$?**

Edit: My initial question was maybe not ideally formulated.

If one is interested in equivariant characteristic classes of a $G$-vector bundle $E$ with a connection $\nabla_E$ and curvature $R_E$, then it is mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06392.pdf (after Def. 4.1) that one can construct a moment map $\mu_E$ using $\nabla_E$, and all interesting equivariant characteristic classes of $E$ seem to be represented by polynomials of the equivariantly closed form
$$
\rho_E(X):=R_E + \mu_E(X).
$$
Therefore, I thought that something similar might hold in the scalar situation.

Edit 2: As explained in my own answer, the special case of an $S^1$-action with isolated fixed points seems to be easy to deal with. It would be very interesting to know if the answer is still affirmative for $S^1$ actions with more general fixed point sets.